# Como hacer que una etiqueta select muestre dos flechas

Tags: html, css

Hola tengo una etiqueta select la cual me muestra mombres de ciudades, sin embargo quiero que la etiquetq select me muestre dos flechas 
algo asi:

[image]

Como puedo hacer eso en el css?

Comment: Creo que solo se puede con JavaScript .....Espere y lo intento y le colaboro

Comment: Eso va a depender del navegador y no es algo que por lo general puedas controlar. Pero quizás sí se pueda definir de navegador en navegador, sería interesante que añadieras algo más de información: ¿te interesa algún navegador en concreto? ¿has investigado algo sobre el tema? ¿has hecho alguna prueba? Quizás podrías definirlo con CSS y una imagen/texto en el `::before`/`::after`, pero sería interesante saber más, para poder determinar qué es exactamente lo que buscas (¿tiene que ser un `select`? ¿puedes cambiar el código? etc) y definitivamente ver el HTML sería ideal

Comment: Amigo aqui esta completo https://programacion.net/articulo/5_plugins_de_jquery_para_personalizar_tus_campos_select_1627

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacer algo con los estilos, modificando el `appearance` y poniendo una imagen como tu flecha deseada.

```css
.form-select {
  width: 200px;
}

.form-select select {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  background: #fff url('https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/arrow-up-icon-23.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: 15px;
  background-position:  right 10px center;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  padding-left: 15px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-select">
  <select name="select">
    <option value="1">Mi valor 1</option>
    <option value="2">Mi valor 2</option>
    <option value="3">Mi valor 3</option>
    <option value="4">Mi valor 4</option>
    <option value="5">Mi valor 5</option>
    <option value="6">Mi valor 6</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: eso si que me sirvio, muchas gracias :)

Comment: De nada, si te ha sido de utilidad, puedes tildar la respuesta como correcta.